# Python3 - Group for loop output together before evaluating?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a script that evaluates a json response. For each response, I want to group them together before evaluating it.

This is an example output (there will be multiple of these outputs every time it runs and the maptoValue would vary in each output):

```
{
    "Output": [{
        "Name": "sample-1",
        "SampleBool": False,
        "MaptoValue": False
    }, {
        "Name": "sample-2",
        "SampleBool": False,
        "MaptoValue": False
    }, {
        "Name": "sample-3",
        "SampleBool": True,
        "MaptoValue": True
    }]
}
```

This is currently what I have:

```
checkVal = []
for i in response['Output']:
    checkVal.append(str(i['MaptoValue']))
    print(checkVal)
```

And it produces this response:

```
['False']
['False', 'True']
['False', 'True', 'False']
```

What I want to happen though is for it to only give me the third response so I can evaluate it where if True is in it then raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have your desired response stored in checkVal, just remove the print from the loop.

```
checkVal = []
for i in response['Output']:
    checkVal.append(str(i['MaptoValue']))
print(checkVal)
```

should now produce

```
['False', 'True', 'False'] # value of checkVal
```

which can be looped over and evaluated

```
for val in checkVal:
    if val == 'False':
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

however, the following code from your original solution will do the same thing

```
for i in response['Output']:
    if str(i['MaptoValue']) == 'False':
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

Id also recommend using boolean `True` and `False` values instead of string `'True'` and `'False'` values. It's much more easy and intuitive to work with.

```
checkVal = [False, True, False]
for condition in checkVal:
    if condition:
        # condition is True, do something
    else:
        # condition is False, do something else
```